# Caprine (messenger client) fails to start

Tags: javascript

I am used to use Caprine as my messenger client on Ubuntu. However, after few months of using in with Ubuntu 18.04 it simply fails to start giving this exception:

```
nicnajder@nicnajder:~$ caprine
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chown '/home/nicnajder/snap/caprine/28/.config/Caprine/config.json.2832388994'
    at Object.chownSync (fs.js:1104:3)
    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/snap/caprine/28/resources/app.asar/node_modules/conf/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:196:27)
    at ElectronStore.set store [as store] (/snap/caprine/28/resources/app.asar/node_modules/conf/index.js:277:19)
    at ElectronStore.set (/snap/caprine/28/resources/app.asar/node_modules/conf/index.js:152:14)
    at updateVibrancySetting (/snap/caprine/28/resources/app.asar/dist-js/config.js:155:15)
    at migrate (/snap/caprine/28/resources/app.asar/dist-js/config.js:165:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snap/caprine/28/resources/app.asar/dist-js/config.js:168:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
```

I tried to reinstall Caprine, but it did not fix the problem. Any ideas what to do?

EDIT:

```
nicnajder@nicnajder:~$ ls -ld /home/nicnajder/snap{,/caprine{,/28{,/.config{,/Caprine{,/config.json.2832388994}}}}}
ls: cannot access '/home/nicnajder/snap/caprine/28/.config/Caprine/config.json.2832388994': No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 5 nicnajder nicnajder 4096 jún 28 12:54 /home/nicnajder/snap
drwxr-xr-x 4 nicnajder nicnajder 4096 aug 22 14:39 /home/nicnajder/snap/caprine
drwxr-xr-x 4 nicnajder nicnajder 4096 aug 22 14:39 /home/nicnajder/snap/caprine/28
drwxr-xr-x 8 nicnajder nicnajder 4096 aug 22 14:39 /home/nicnajder/snap/caprine/28/.config
drwxr-xr-x 2 nicnajder nicnajder 4096 aug 23 12:33 /home/nicnajder/snap/caprine/28/.config/Caprine
```

Comment: @Nicnajder Can you **[edit]** your question to give the output of `ls -ld /home/nicnajder/snap{,/caprine{,/28{,/.config{,/Caprine{,/config.json.2832388994}}}}}` and to say whether or not you've ever run the program as root, such as with `sudo`? To be clear, *please do **not** try to run it is as root*; the reason I'm asking for that information is that I believe doing that may have caused this problem.

Comment: @EliahKagan - Question edited. I did not run the program as root.

Comment: Yep, also having this problem. What distro are you running? Mint?

Comment: @Gaul I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/caprine/issues/1062

You could manually install version 2.36.0, which is not affected by this problem:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/caprine/releases/tag/v2.36.0

Or use snap revert if you updated from a previous version.